# odata filtering based on the property of a relation

Tags: rest, odata, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to filter a set based on an aspect of their item relations called "listcontact_association" which represents the N:N relationship between contacts and lists.

I can retrieve the whole set ok by getting:

```
/ContactSet?$select=listcontact_association,FirstName,LastName,EMailAddress1&$expand=listcontact_association
```

Which gives me:

[image]

But what I would like to have is to be able to only get those Contacts that belong to an specific List based on a guid:

```
ContactSet?$select=listcontact_association,FirstName,LastName,EMailAddress1&$expand=listcontact_association,FirstName,LastName,EMailAddress1&$filter=listcontact_association/ListId %20eq%20(guid%2787F2A0AF-A142-E411-93FA-000C29482C88%27)
```

This tells me:

```
No property 'ListId' exists in type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]' at position 24.
```

which I guess makes sense as there can be many list associations.

I am an odata newbie and can't figure out how to filter my data, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because listcontact_association is a collection, in this case, you can use lamda expression based on your requirement (only list out the filter clause here):

filter by any listid match the condition.

```
$filter=listcontact_association/any(a:a/ListId%20eq%20(guid%2787F2A0AF-A142-E411-93FA-000C29482C88%27))
```

filter by all listid match the condition

```
$filter=listcontact_association/all(a:a/ListId%20eq%20(guid%2787F2A0AF-A142-E411-93FA-000C29482C88%27))
```